# SMS is not received on dual sim

Tags: android, smsmanager

I write a simple code to receive SMS and store it in the database. for mobile with just one sim, it works fine. But when I import the second sim into mobile my code did not work. below is my code:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public AppDBHelper db;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("receiveSMS","sms 1");
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle==null) return;
        Object[] pdus= (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        if(pdus==null) return;
        SmsMessage[] messages=new SmsMessage[pdus.length];//num of messages
        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                String format=bundle.getString("format");
                messages[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i],format);
            }else{
                messages[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            String messageText=messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            messageText=messageText.replaceAll(" ","");
            messageText=messageText.replaceAll("\n","");
            messageText=messageText.replaceAll("\u200E","");
            if(messageText!=null) {
                db.insertSmsCodes(messageText);// insert into database
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I also add these permissions to manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Where is my wrong?

Comment: Exactly what is the problem? Any error log?

Comment: Did you register receiver in manifest?

Comment: Khemraj  yes, I register it in the manifest. @HarshitAgrawal  my problem is that if I insert the second sim into my mobile this receiver does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code this is working fine in all my projects.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.text.TextUtils;

/**
 * Created by KHEMRAJ on 4/11/2017.
 */

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (TextUtils.equals(intent.getAction(), SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION)) {
            Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
            if (data != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
                if (pdus != null) {
                    for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                        String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageBody)) {
                            // your stuff here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your manifest

```
   <receiver
            android:name=".utils.SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Only this permission is needed for receiving SMS

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

You are good to go :)

Comment: `Try this code` is not a good way to answer . Please point out what was wrong with the Op's approach. And what correction you have made .

Comment: Welcome dude ZahraTz, @ADM sir what you say :)

Comment: hahaha .. What are u talking about ? I asked you to explain the problem the op's code . Why being so dramatic. Thats how your answer will be more useful . If you do not explain the problem this will just encourage copy-paste of code . it will not clarify the Concept  .

Comment: which one of the code that detect multi sim card?